Can I reconnect a battery to pull up windows while alternator is out?
I am in the process of changing out the alternator. The old one is out, the new one is not in yet. I won't be able to get to it until tomorrow and I forgot to pull up the windows. Because the negative battery terminal is disconnected, I can neither pull up windows nor lock the car.
Is it safe to reconnect the battery just so I can turn the ignition to ON to pull up the windows? Or could this throw some error codes or worse?

Aside - Don't try to start the car, it could confuse any computer and loose wires could get tangled in moving parts like belts.   You can lock the car with the key manually at any time, though not much use if the windows are open.

Yes, it should not cause any issues. Just ensure the larger red wire which would usually be connected to the alternator is isolated so it won't come in contact with a ground. As long as you do this, you shouldn't have an issue.

I isolated all the cables connected to the alternator in small plastic box so they won't make contact with any part of the body. After that I was able to close the windows and lock the car.

@cryptic0 - Make sure you disconnect the battery before you start installing the new alternator.

Yep, I disconnected the battery first when I started working on the car again. I have run into another major issue, but I will post it in a separate thread.
